# How to run a SolidWorks macro directly using Python

Tags: python, solidworksapi

Is there a way where I can run a SolidWorks macro using python? Either by running the full script (macro) directly from a Python IDE, or by even writing a python script that could somehow open SolidWorks and run my pre-saved `.swp` macro, preferably in batch mode.

Comment: `import os`, then do `os.popen('"Path to SLDWORKS.exe" /m "Path to a macro"')` Using the `/m` flag you can force solid works to open then run the desired macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a SolidWorks macro by executing a terminal command

```
import os
os.popen('"Path to SLDWORKS.exe" /m "Path to a macro"')
```